# How to call NSUserDefaults Observer from iOS-Extension in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, nsuserdefaults, sharing, ios-app-group

I try to Upload Pictures from iPhone to my Xamarin-PCL-App.
I'm using a Share-Extension and iOS App-groups.
My Main-App Observer on changing NSUserDefaults isn't called, when the Extension changes something.

I try to Upload Pictures from iPhone to my Xamarin-PCL-App.
I'm using a Share-Extension.
I already have implemented the extension, it's working fine.
I can choose my App as target in the galery after klicking the share-button.
The DidSelectPost() Event of the Extension is called and I can show a Message on the iPhone.
Now I want to enter my Main-App to handle the incoming Picture.
I added an app-group to my App and the Extension (in the entitlement.plist Files it is already there).
Now I should be able to let the Main-App and the Extension communicate via NSUserDefaults, right?

I added the following Code in the Main-Apps AppDelegate in FinishedLaunching:

```
var userDefaults = new NSUserDefaults("group.de.companyname.appname", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
            userDefaults.AddObserver("rate", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Prior, note =>
            {
                NSUserDefaults shared = new NSUserDefaults("group.de.companyname.appname", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
                var value = shared.ValueForKey(new NSString("rate"));
            });
```

It should be called on changes in NSUserDefaults key named "rate".
If I change this Value in the Main-App the Event is called.

I added a simple change in the ViewContollers (Type: SLComposeServiceViewController) DidSelectPost Function:

```
NSUserDefaults shared = new NSUserDefaults("group.de.companyname.appname", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
shared.SetString("test", "rate");
            shared.Synchronize();
```

My Main-App just doesn't get the changes.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should **AddObserver** in where you changed the value, such as `ViewContollers` you used.

**Main-Apps AppDelegate**:

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
shared.SetString("testOldData", "rate");
shared.Synchronize();
```

**ViewContollers** :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
base.ViewDidLoad ();

NSUserDefaults shared = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
shared.AddObserver(this, "Name", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, IntPtr.Zero);
}

//Test Changing the value
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{ 
base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
NSUserDefaults shared = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
shared.SetString("testNewData", "rate");
shared.Synchronize();
}
```

And when value changed , this method can be invoked:

```
//When value cahnged this will be invoked
public override void ObserveValue(NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
{
    if (keyPath == "Name")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--old--" + change.ValueForKey(new NSString("old")));
        Console.WriteLine("--new--" + change.ValueForKey(new NSString("new")));
    }
    else
        base.ObserveValue(keyPath, ofObject, change, context);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Junior Jiang - MSFT

I added your Code in my programm, but it still does nothing.

Any Idea why?

Comment: Got it, Suggest using `NSUserDefaults shared=SUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;` instead of `NSUserDefaults shared = new NSUserDefaults("group.de.companyname.appname", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);`to have a try.I will update answer.@L.B.

Comment: Nothing happens.. 
I still don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: @L.B. Eh, you can post your sample project.I will chck it.